# Java location path regex split

Tags: java, windows, selenium, cucumber

I've "inherited" existing Java Selenium & Cucumber framework which was written mostly for OS usage. I'm using Windows and I'm trying to fix & run it on Windows.

My first problem is specifing corrent file path, this is how it was written for OS:

```
private String getProjectName(Scenario scenario) {
    return Arrays.asList(scenario.getUri().getPath().replace(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "").split("/")).get(5);
}
```

Error which I'm receiving is:
**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 1**

As for Windows we're using backlashes I've tried switching "/" into "" but as error appears (+ after my investigations) I've tried with "\\\\" but actually error remains the same as above.

I'm aware that providing only portion of my code and it may be hard but for the first glance can you tell me:

- If that method may work on Windows or this should be completely refactored?
- Is `System.getProperty("user.dir")` correct solution?
- How to correctly pass backslashes?
- Why they're taking `.get(5)`?

Comment: "why they're taking get(5)" -> you will have to ask the original authors about that. They probably assumed that the scenario is stored in a specific directory on your system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I can guess:**

This method is taking the project name that is likely the name of a certain folder in the folder structure where scenario file located.

This is why they took `5`th element. Because on the `5`th level there was the folder which represented the project.

The used approach look very arguable. At least because there are some redundent steps like converting to list.

**Now. How would you go:**

The proper way is to use `java.nio.file.Path` (starts from Java 7) that takes care of differnt OS-specific things.

So your code might look like:

```java
private String getProjectName(Scenario scenario) {
  return Path.of(scenario.getUri()).getName(5)
}
```

**P.S.** - of course you have to change `5` to catch a proper position of the required folder in your structure.